# Ability to execute code on a device when the debugger detaches

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I found recently that calling TAPI's lineInitializeEx() without a corresponding lineShutdown() causes the visual studio debugger to hang for around 10 to 20 seconds on detach (shift-f5).

Is it possible to detect in my Windows CE application when the IDE requests the application debugger detach? On that hook, I want to be able to execute some cleanup code.

This will allow me to gracefully shut the application down - even when a developer uses 'shift-f5' from the IDE...

Comment: The debugger error I get is "Unable to stop debugging. Operation not supported. Unknown Error: 0x800400c3". This is a native app.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the same error here. Since there are no google hints and nothing in the MSDN to find about that error I assume its an error resulting from our miss-behaving applications. I would guess it is a threading issue. One thread cannot be terminated correctly.